# Activities and Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications

To regularly remind the user that something has to be done, I use a timer to periodically refresh a `Notification` with a new message. This process must only stop when the user clicks on the `Notification`, which causes the corresponding `Activity` to be launched with an `Intent` containing a flag specifying that the `Activity` is started by a `Notification`. In the `onResume` function of my main `Activity`, I retrieve this flag and check it. If it is set, I do what is necessary to stop the periodic reminder.

I obtain this behaviour if my application is not active when the user clicks on the `Notification`, but if the `Activity` is already launched, the periodic reminder continues again and again. I specify that my `Activity` is launched in `singleInstance` mode.

How can I do to receive and treat the `Intent` sent by the `Notification` in my already active `Activity`?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `singleInstance` mode.You would need to override `onNewIntent(Intent)` to receive new Intents for the Activity and do your work there

Also, you may want to call `setIntent(intent)` in onNewIntent to make sure future calls to `getIntent()` within the Activity lifecycle get the most recent Intent data.